# Using python pip can i install only the imports I'm using with the relevant dependencies? (for aws lambda)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip

I try to use pip to install **only the imports I'm using with their dependencies** in python venv 
this is for uploading the zip to AWS lambda.
but when I do install its download me huge directory structure
I'm not sure I need all of it.
my question is how can I download **only the imports I'm using from package**
for example :
I'm using :

```
from exchangelib import DELEGATE, Account, Credentials, Configuration
```

and when I'm doing (in the isolated python env):

```
pip install exchangelib
```

it install's me :

```
Pygments-2.6.1.dist-info
__pycache__
_cffi_backend.cp36-win32.pyd
cached_property-1.5.1.dist-info
cached_property.py
certifi
certifi-2019.11.28.dist-info
cffi
cffi-1.14.0.dist-info
chardet
chardet-3.0.4.dist-info
cryptography
cryptography-2.8.dist-info
dateutil
defusedxml
defusedxml-0.6.0.dist-info
dns
dnspython-1.16.0.dist-info
easy_install.py
idna
idna-2.9.dist-info
isodate
isodate-0.6.0.dist-info
lxml
lxml-4.5.0.dist-info
ntlm_auth
ntlm_auth-1.4.0.dist-info
oauthlib
oauthlib-3.1.0.dist-info
pip
pip-18.1.dist-info
pkg_resources
pycparser
pycparser-2.20.dist-info
pygments
python_dateutil-2.8.1.dist-info
pytz
pytz-2019.3.dist-info
requests
requests-2.23.0.dist-info
requests_ntlm
requests_ntlm-1.1.0.dist-info
requests_oauthlib
requests_oauthlib-1.3.0.dist-info
setuptools
setuptools-40.6.2.dist-info
six-1.14.0.dist-info
six.py
tzlocal
tzlocal-2.0.0.dist-info
urllib3
urllib3-1.25.8.dist-info
```

Comment: That just means that these are all needed dependencies (e.g. what `exchangelib` declares as dependencies). If you want to have it reproducible, you can make a requirements.txt from `pip freeze`.

Comment: Also, if you want to install it in AWS, you may download all the needed packages (probably wheels), deploy these, and install them on deployment, instead of zipping the installed packages (as I understand you do now).

Comment: what that means ? "and install them on deployment," ? 
where can i read about it in AWS lambda doc?

Comment: install on deployment means you need to deploy while deploying your source code. create a pip freeze, using pip install -r requirements.txt to download the dependencies...package the zip and upload to AWS lambda